# Conditional querying based on the current date & time

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have an sql query in which I need to select the records from table where the time is between 3:00 PM yesterday to 3:00 PM today *if* today's time is more than 3:00 PM.

If today's time is less than that, like if today's time is 1:00 PM. then then my query should take today's time as 1:00 PM (which should return me records).

**I need to get the time between 3:00pm yesterday to 3:00pm today if todays time is more than 3:00pm
if todays time is less than 3:00pm then get the 3:00pm yesterday to current time today**

Comment: Does the table contain a CreateDate field?

Comment: hi i need to get the time between 3:00pm yesterday to 3:00pm today if todays time is more than 3:00pm if todays time is less than 3:00pm then get the 3:00pm yesterday to current time today

Comment: In what way does posting the same block of text in your question, as a comment to your question and as a comment to the first answer in any way make things more clear? Have you read the stackoverflow FAQ?

Comment: got the answer any way sorry , if my question is confusing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of handling this is to use an [IF statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php):

```
IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24') >= 15 THEN 

  SELECT x.*
    FROM YOUR_TABLE x
   WHERE x.date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')|| ' 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                           AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')|| ' 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

ELSE

  SELECT x.*
    FROM YOUR_TABLE x
   WHERE x.date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')|| ' 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                           AND SYSDATE

END IF;
```

Conditional WHERE clauses are non-sargable.

### Previously:

If I understand correctly, you want to get records within the last day.  If the current time is 3 PM or later, the time should be set to 3 PM.  If earlier than 3 PM, take the current time...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE x
  JOIN (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24') >= 15 THEN 
                  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')|| ' 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                 ELSE SYSDATE
               END AS dt
          FROM DUAL) y ON x.date_column BETWEEN dt - 1 AND dt
```

#### Note:

`dt - 1` means that 24 hours will be subtracted from the Oracle DATE.

#### Reference:

- [TO_CHAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)
- [TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: hi i need to get the time between 3:00pm yesterday to 3:00pm today if todays time is more than 3:00pm if todays time is less than 3:00pm then get the 3:00pm yesterday to current time today, thanks for ansher

Comment: You don't need conditionals, just get all records till 15:00 today, no matter what time it is. The DB won't have records from the future :)

Comment: Thank you very much OMG Ponies and Vladislav Zorov

Comment: @Vladislav Zorov: What if the system (or table) only allows inserting dates from the future?  You're casting assumptions...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an IF statement.  This can be solved easily with simple SQL.

My table T23 has some records with dates; here is a sample with times at 3.00pm:

```
SQL> select id, some_date from t23
  2  where to_char(some_date,'HH24') = '15'
  3  /

        ID SOME_DATE
---------- ---------
        14 16-MAY-11
        38 17-MAY-11
        62 18-MAY-11
        81 19-MAY-11

SQL>
```

As the current time is before 3.00pm my query will return records from 17-MAY and 18-MAY but not the record where ID=62...

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') as time_now
  2  from dual
  3  /

TIME_NOW
-----------------
18-MAY-2011 10:45

SQL> select id, to_char(some_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') as dt
  2  from t23
  3  where some_date between trunc(sysdate-1)+(15/24)
  4                  and least( trunc(sysdate)+(15/24), sysdate)
  5  /

        ID DT
---------- -----------------
        38 17-MAY-2011 15:00
        39 17-MAY-2011 16:00
        40 17-MAY-2011 17:00
        41 17-MAY-2011 18:00
        42 17-MAY-2011 19:00
        43 17-MAY-2011 20:00
        44 17-MAY-2011 21:00
        45 17-MAY-2011 22:00
        46 17-MAY-2011 23:00
        47 18-MAY-2011 00:00
        48 18-MAY-2011 01:00
        49 18-MAY-2011 02:00
        50 18-MAY-2011 03:00
        51 18-MAY-2011 04:00
        52 18-MAY-2011 05:00
        53 18-MAY-2011 06:00
        54 18-MAY-2011 07:00
        55 18-MAY-2011 08:00
        56 18-MAY-2011 09:00
        57 18-MAY-2011 10:00

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```